# Apache : empty body when deflate input

Tags: apache, mod-deflate

When I send a gzip request to apache, when apache is configured with "SetInputFilter DEFLATE", my request body is empty on apache output.
The content is not empty but still compressed whithout this configuration.

Do you know what am I missing ? Do you know how I could have more informations about a possible error in decompression with the module mod_deflate ?

The documentation of this module with my apache (2.2) is here :
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request content was filtered by the module weblogic (mod_wl). We can use either another module apache or uncompress in Java Controller.